# Problem with understanding Article called - "Recognition Math expression from Image. MST and symbol dominance algorithm"

Tags: parsing, math, expression, structure, article

Need Help!
There is the article [MST and symbol dominance](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-25977-0_30). In this article in section 2.3 (Baseline Representation of Expressions) there is a function called - getDominantBaseline(Db, L), and this function uses another function getRightNeighbor, but authors suddenly forgot to write this function explanation
Does anybody known what the getRightNeighbor function do?

Please Help!

I tried to search but first i decided to ask a question here)